# How to load external XAML ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, xaml, resourcedictionary

How can I add ResourceDictionary dinamicly like this?

```
ResourceDictionary template = new ResourceDictionary();
template.Source = new Uri("Design.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(template);
```

With absolute Uri it working perfectly but from Relative doesnt.

Comment: do you have the Design.xaml in the same folder your assembly is running in?

Answer (score 1):

I use the XamlReader class to do this:

```
string exeFilePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
string exeDirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(exeFilePath);
string targetFile = "subfolder\\dictionary.xaml";
string path_to_xaml_dictionary = new Uri(Path.Combine(exeDirPath, targetFile)).LocalPath;
string strXaml = File.ReadAllText(path_to_xaml_dictionary);                    
ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Parse(strXaml);
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary);
```

Works pretty well for me.